# gdalwarp from within python script misbehaving

Tags: python, gdalwarp

I'm trying to run gdalwarp from within a python script

```
    start = "gdalwarp -overwrite -ts 22 20 -r average -srcnodata 99 "
    input_file = filename[12:]
    output_file = "temp1.tif"
    print start + input_file + ' ' +output_file
    subprocess.call([r'%s %s output.tif' % (start, input_file)],  shell=True )
```

Where `filename` changes iteratively (i'm batch processing and this is the first step). However when i run the script i get for example:

```
ERROR 4: `200301.h11v09.tif' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

But when i run the code on `200301.h11v09.tif` in terminal it works perfectly. I feel like it's something to do with python string substitution but don't know enough to figure out myself now.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try it with a different filename. It might fail because of the two dots in your filename.

Comment: Makes no difference unfortunately same error with 200301h11v09.tif :(

Answer (score 1):

Drop the brackets around the first argument to `subprocess.call`. It's designed to take either a the command string as a single argument, or as a list of arguments that will be separated by a space. Here you are supplying the whole argument in one, so give it as a string, not a list.